# How to open two versions of Qt Creator using cmd

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator

I'm working on Windows 7 and already installed Qt Creator 3.3 and Qt Creator 2.4.1 in my PC.

I'm trying to open Qt Creator by typing ***qtcreator*** in cmd. When I press 'enter' I get loaded Qt Creator which first appears in the PATH variable. (I checked after swap the positions of both in PATH)

But I don't know how to open the two version at different times.

I'm searching a way to use alias when set the PATH. Something like qtcreator3.3 and qtcreator2.4 or any other.

Comment: Why do you still want to use 2.4.1? (given that 3.6.0 is current…). I think 2.4.1 and 3.3 will share the same settings and 2.4.1 may have issue with reading or even corrupt settings written by 3.3.

Comment: Our team is working on 2.4.1 since the beginning of project (long time ago) we are working on. I personally thought to move the project to later version. 
Till it move I decide to get familiar with new one also. That's why I want to use two versions. Anyway I can open both using 'explorer'. Just asked how I can do same via CMD.

Comment: "I personally thought to move the project to later version” - there’s nothing in the *project* you need to touch when using a newer Qt creator as your IDE (opposed to a newer Qt or different compiler). Also, what others use is secondary, one person can happily use Qt Creator while the other uses emacs, vi (or even notepad ;) ). The project in your version control system should see nothing of either setup.

Comment: I successfully moved to latest version. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really just use the newer version of Qt creator (or upgrade all the way to the latest release) but set it up to use the older versions of Qt that the project uses. Qt Creator is just an IDE, there's no reason you can't use a newer version than other people, as long as you're all building with the same version of Qt and same compiler/linker.

Also, why command line? You can just create start menu shortcuts for each one. Start typing qt after bringing up the start menu and windows will show both for you to click on.

But if you really must do what you asked, you can create shortcuts to the qt creator executables, then name them whatever you want, and put them somewhere on your PATH (like right next to the actual .exe). Then if you want to be able to launch qt creator v3.3 from a command line, you can run qtcreator3.3.lnk, or follow this question: https://superuser.com/questions/227877/running-shortcut-from-command-prompt-without-the-lnk-extension-windows to call it without having to type .lnk.